# What is the best way to see all the ssr/csr components hierarchy or diagram?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I would like to have a map/diagram that shows me all the client side and the server side components.

Are there any extension\plugin that helps with that?

My goal is to make as many of the components as possible server-side components.

Comment: Software recommendations are off topic here. Please see the [help].